# Can I back out of an international hiring contract?

Tags: software-industry, software

I am currently working in Dubai in a large national company, as a Senior Machine Learning Engineer (SMLE). Here the salaries are good and there is no income tax. However, I recently passed the interview for Amazon for the role of SDE II. This was a tough interview and a lot of leetcode-style practice and some luck was needed :). I'm not sure I could easily just walk into getting hired again in the future.

I was excited due it being Amazon, and thus a [FAANG](https://cleartax.in/glossary/faang/) company. This is a very good company to work for as a Software developer. However the role in Europe, and after tax would mean *my take-home pay would be almost half what I currently earn* even with stock options included. It's mid-level (vs my current senior position), and it's a software role vs AI/Big-data (I originally started out as a software dev and wanted to transition into the world of ML, so in some sense seems like a step back).

I'm struggling to decide what to do. I know short-term financially that sticking with my current position will be more lucrative, but long-term it's harder to say. The prestige of Amazon on my resume may open doors in the future, and lead to longer term gains, however the fact it's software vs ML, may be a negative in the future (depending on where ChatGPT/Co-pilot and so on lead us). Working for amazon and with talented people could be inspiring and help hone my skills, plus present networking opportunities that translate to increased income down the line.

The other factor is that I am in my first few months in the current position and didn't yet clear probation and I won't do so until around April/May. Amazon would want me to start in June. I'm thinking of saying "yes" at least as a hedge in case I don't clear probation and then properly deciding in May whether to go or stay. Is there any legal implication of doing so if they start a visa application and I sign a contract but don't end up going in the end? I just don't want to turn it down, not pass probation in my current role then end up with neither....

Comment: There is a valid question in the last paragraph , .after all the irrelevancies about the difficulty of making the decision have been pruned away. (Seriously, all the history and personal struggles just discourage folks from reading far enough to get to the question you have actually asked. We can't advise on which option to choose.)

Comment: Always, accept a new position before resigning.

Comment: The following article is about Meta, but I think the same lesson can apply to Amazon. https://interviewing.io/blog/how-to-negotiate-with-meta Basically tell them it's not enough, they're most likely lowballing you. If they ask for a competing offer, tell them your current salary and the tax benefits you enjoy. That's it. Draw that line in the sand. If they don't believe you're willing to walk away from them, they're not going to improve their offer to you.

Answer (score 2):

Money vs. prestige is a *classic* Personal Choice. Only you know how you want to weight each one. Social factors, cost of living, access to other opportunities and resources may also play into it. Write down everything you can think of for and against each choice, balance how *you* feel about them, and pick one or roll the dice. Nobody else knows your priorities.

If you are asking only about the legal question, most of what you've told us is irrelevant. The answer depends on the laws of the country the contract was signed under, the exact wording of the contract, and international law.

People do back out of employment contracts all the time, for various good and bad reasons; the question of whether you would be liable for the visa costs and the like is not at all clear. You really need an expert opinion for your specific case, not
a bunch of amateurs on the Internet hypothesizing without all the details, training, or experience.

It's unlikely Amazon would hold you up for more than their sunk costs, for whatever that is worth. But I can't promise that; I am not a lawyer.